# How do I prevent Backbone from updating the model when save is called?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I call save on a Backbone model...

```
model.save();
```

...Backbone expects a JSON response from the server, which it uses to update the model.

How do I prevent Backbone from updating the model when save is called?

Comment: You can't, at least not without extending Backbone and probably overriding `save`.  The `success` callback in `save` sets the attributes, and there's no provided way to change that.

Comment: Could you describe what problem are you trying to solve?  Seems like something that can be solved without diverting from basic behavior of Backbone classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it

```
model.clone().save()
```

Original `model` will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should just use `model.set(attributes, [options])` [Model-set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set).

A "change" event will be triggered on the model. No HTTP `POST`/`PUT` request

```
model = new Application({id: 1, title: 'test'})
model.set({attr: 'value', key: 'val'})

model.toJSON()
// => {id: 1, title: "test", attr: "value", key: "val"}
```